# Can co-owner of an apartment prohibit tenants to use bathroom (wc). Is it a violation of the right of adequate housing (UN HABITAT)?

Tags: international

Can co-owner of an apartment prohibit tenants to use bathroom (wc).

Is it a violation of the right of adequate housing (UN HABITAT)?

Can co-owner evict tenants without providing an alternative accommodation?
Use it's rights to abuse rights of another co-owner who provided a room of an apartment for tenants

Please note rooms are isolated and aren't shared property of the two co-owners.
Co-owner cannot prohibit to rent an room of apartment

Common areas (bathroom, kitchen) are shared property.

Can co-owner (who want to evict) refuse of fair compensation?

Comment: There are over 190 countries in the world, all of which have different views on your questions - indeed, some countries have differing views and laws depending on where you live in that country.  Where are you interested in, specifically?

Comment: UN pronouncements are almost never self-executing. Any remedy must arise from the locally adopted law of the jurisdiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right to adequate housing is a political question, the content of which is unclear in the [UN's fact sheet](https://www.un.org/ruleoflaw/files/FactSheet21en.pdf). What they say is:

> All beneficiaries of the right to adequate housing should have
> sustainable access to natural and common resources, clean drinking
> water, energy for cooking, heating and lighting, sanitation and
> washing facilities, food storage facilities, refuse disposal, site
> drainage and emergency services.

Sanitation facilities are not completely ignored, so there is a theoretical basis to start from. However, that list of desiderata is not legally enforceable, so it would depends on the laws of the particular jurisdiction. In the [state of Washington (US)](https://apps.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=59.18&full=true), a rental that lacked any sanitary facility (toilet) would be a violation of the health code: even hot water is required by law. In other countries, esp. where running water is not ubiquitous, there may be no legal obligation for a landlord to provide a toilet with running water. Whether legal action could be taken against the landlord depends on local law.

A property owner can evict a tenant, subject again to local law. Usually, it requires a legal process where the owner petitions the court to evict the tenant, and in case the tenant has a contractual right to be there, the owner has to show cause (tenant breached the terms of the lease). A landlord does not generally have an obligation to find alternative housing for a tenant, but perhaps there is such a law somewhere, related to tenant tenure.

The mention of a co-owner is a bit confusing. If A is the sole owner of a property, A can exercise landlord rights. If A and B both own the property, either of them can exercise landlord rights. However, if they disagree, i.e. A wants to evict tenant C and B wants to let C stay, the dispute between A and B must be resolved, and if they cannot come to an agreement then B can cause a delay of the eviction until the dispute is resolved in court. Again, the details on this would depend on the jurisdiction, and in part whatever landlord-tenant laws there are.